# Remove links in admin content list form

Tags: 7, forms

In the admin content form (admin/content), I am trying to remove links to content page on some content types in a custom module with the following code but I can't get it working.

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_node_admin_content_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_veilleur_form_node_admin_content_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    foreach ($form['admin']['nodes']['#options'] as $option){
      if($option['type'] == "Document"){
        $option['title']['data']['#type'] = "text";
        unset($option['title']['data']['#href']);
      }
    }
}
```

With this code, I still have the links in the content title. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it is my fault, I forgot to use the "&" to pass the reference variable in the loop. Here is the final code :

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_node_admin_content_alter()
 */
function MYMODULE_veilleur_form_node_admin_content_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    foreach ($form['admin']['nodes']['#options'] as &$option){
      if($option['type'] == "Document"){
        $option['title'] = $option['title']['data']['#title'];
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work too...

```
function YOURMODULE_form_node_admin_content_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  foreach ($form['admin']['nodes']['#options'] as $key => $value){
    if($form['admin']['nodes']['#options'][$key]['type'] == "Document"){
      $form['admin']['nodes']['#options'][$key]['title']['data']['#type'] = "item";
      unset($form['admin']['nodes']['#options'][$key]['title']['data']['#href']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes it works fine too.thks